# Bluetooth Keyboard not functioning properly Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, bluetooth, peripherals

I recently bought a Bluetooth keyboard (when I still had Windows) and then decided to upgrade my laptop `HP Envy x360 Convertible 15-aq055na` to Arch Linux (KDE Plasma if that helps). Everything is working fine (mouse), except my keyboard.

I've installed Blueman, and I've managed to connect the keyboard to my PC, the number keys and numeric keypad, all seem to work, just not the letter keys. Can someone please help me fix this problem because I don't want my keyboard gathering dust?